# Dual space $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-analysis

Take a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{E},\mathbb{P}).$ Then it is known that $L^\infty \subset L^p \subset L^q \subset L^1$ for $\infty \ge p \ge q \ge 1.$

Let $l: L^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the functional $l_p(f):=\int_{\Omega} f.$ Then by this reasoning $l_p$ is bounded for every $p.$

Hence, one can look at the Banach space $X_p:=\text{ker}(l_p).$ Now, I was wondering  whether the dual space of $X_p$ is $X_q:=\text{ker}(l_q)$ or if there is another way to characterize the dual space of $X_p$ for $1\le p < \infty$?

I should add that for $U$ being a closed subspace of a Banach space $X$ we have the canonical isomorphism $U'=X'/U^\perp,$ where $U^\perp$ is the annihilator (not the orthogonal complement) of $U$. So this actually answers the question in a way, but I don't know what this means for my concrete situation.

I tried working with the hints in the comments:

So if $l_p: L^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have $l_p^* : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (L^p)^*.$

I guess now that for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f \in L^p$ we have
$l_p^*(x) = \int_{\Omega} x(.),$ so $l_p^*(f) = \int_{\Omega} xf.$ Hence, $\text{ran}(l_p^*)$ consists of all the linear functions $\int_{\Omega}x(.)$ where $x$ is some real constant. Now the big question is, can we identify $L^q/\text{ran}(l_p^*)$ with something less abstract?

Comment: Have you tried to identify the subspace $U^{\perp} = (\operatorname{ker}(l_p))^{\perp}$?

Comment: unfortunately I don't see how we can identify the annihilator with something useful. But besides, my final goal would also be to identify $X'/U^\perp$ with something familiar

Comment: You have $\operatorname{ker}(l_p)^\perp = \operatorname{closure}(\operatorname{range}(l_p^*))$, where $l_p^* : \mathbb{R} \to L^q$ is the adjoint of $l_p$. So $U^\perp$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $L^q$. If you have a precise expression for this subspace, you also get an idea of $X'/U^\perp$.

Comment: @gerw I added my thoughts to the question body.

Comment: By using the identification of $(L^p)^*$ and $L^q$, the range of $l_p^*$ are the constant functions in $L^q$. So functions in $L^q$ belong to the same equivalence class in $L^q / U^\perp$ iff they differ by a constant.

Comment: @gerw but doesn't this mean that $L^q/U^\perp$ is isomorphic to the space $ker(l_q)$? (just pick the representative or add a constant to the respective function such that its integral is zero)

Comment: Yes, but you have to check that this bijection is actually continuous. You might compile everything into an answer and answer your own question.